# Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition buying query

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

So if I buy The Meizu MX4 from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NWBQAS0)

Then can I install Ubuntu Touch on it without too much of a hassle?  Also where can I buy the phone with Ubuntu Touch already installed in the US?  This one comes with something called Flyme 4.0, which is based on Android.  I can't buy the phone from the Ubuntu website because they don't sell it in the US.  Also it is sold out.

http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/devices

Thanks for any help!